# Is there a way to tell Gradle to include dependencies Javadocs in generated Javadocs?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, javadoc, build.gradle

I have a Java project that I am managing with Gradle. Such project will be composed by multiple small libraries, which are developed independently one another, and a "leaf" project whose goal is just to depend on the latest stable version of each library, package everything in a fat Jar and provide aggregated documentation.

Each library will be uploaded as a separate artifact on Maven Central.

In order to test the feasibility of such configuration, I have written a very simple project which depends on GNU Trove4j.
I'd like to be able to generate a Javadoc for this project that includes both my source code's and Trove4j's code, but so far I have had no success.

My idea would be to import dependencies' sources from Central as part of Gradle's sourceSet, but I have no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to add all the dependencies you want documented to a separate configuration that you then add to the `javadoc` task. Here is a quick example with a couple of simple libraries:

```
configurations {
    doc {
        transitive false
    }
}

dependencies {
    doc 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1:sources'
    doc 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1:sources'
}

javadoc {
    source configurations.doc.collect { zipTree(it) }
    include '**/*.java'
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
}
```

Comment: @DaniloPianini; hello, IBAW but I find your answer very useful. Quick question: does *a separate configuration* mean more than 1 build.gradle file in 1 project? If so, please how/where could I include that second file so I can use this answer. NetBeans oriented if possible :) Thanx

Comment: @Scaramouche, no, a single build.gradle file can host as many configurations as you need, it's the `configurations` block you see in Mark's answer.

If you want to see the proposed solution in action, take a look at the [Alchemist's build.gradle file](https://github.com/AlchemistSimulator/Alchemist/blob/15760342bcd1f8d260b96c5733b2feb13f0b1f8a/alchemist/build.gradle)